# For which $n$, this integral is finite.

Tags: calculus, integration

I don't know how to attack this problem, so I hope someone could help me:

> Find for which $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, the next integral is finite:
>   $$\int^{\infty}_1x^ndx $$

Is obvious that for $n>0$, it won't be, but I don't know how to do it for $n<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ \int_{1}^Rx^n\;dx=\frac{R^{n+1}-1}{n+1} $$
if $n\neq -1$, and
$$ \int_1^R\frac{dx}{x}=\log R $$
Now take the limit as $R\to\infty$.

Comment: Why you get the $\log R$?

Comment: The antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\log x=\ln(x)$.

Comment: I meant about why you needed that, but now I understood that is for the case of $n= -1$.